# block permission in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-permissions

is it possible in Drupal to show a menu just to a special username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without extra modules:

1. First, **create a new role** (in "`Administer > User Management > Roles`")
2. then **assign this new role to the user** you want to show the block to (in "`Administer > User Management > Users`")
3. then in the block's properties (at "`Administer > Blocks`"), **select only that role in visibility options**.

Comment: i guessed i had to set permission for menu not block and so i didn't find such property in menu setting.Thanks wildpeaks. :)